# Objective C send message to creator

Tags: objective-c

I don't quite understand about how to deal with next kind of task:

```
@implementation SomeInterface

-(void)DoSomething
{
     MyObj * mo = [MyObj new];
     [mo doJob];
}
end
```

The question is - how can mo send message back to SomeInterface after doJob is finished?
Should I use NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 4, probably the easiest thing to do is to pass a block to `doJob` that dictates what it should do upon completion. So, for example...

MyObj.h:

```
// create a typedef for our type of completion handler, to make
// syntax cleaner elsewhere
typedef void (^MyObjDoJobCompletionHandler)(void);

@interface MyObj

- (void)doJobWithCompletionHandler:(MyObjDoJobCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@end
```

MyObj.m:

```
- (void)doJobWithCompletionHandler:(MyObjDoJobCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    /* do job here ... */

    // we're done, so give the completion handler a shout.
    // We call it exactly like a C function:
    completionHandler();

    /* alternatives would have been to let GCD dispatch it,
    but that would lead to discussion of GCD and a bunch of
    thread safety issues that aren't really relevant */
}
```

Within SomeInterface.m:

```
-(void)DoSomething
{
     MyObj * mo = [MyObj new];
     [mo doJobWithCompletionHandler:
         ^() // you can omit the brackets if there are no parameters, but
             // that's a special case and I don't want to complicate things...
         {
             NSLog(@"whoop whoop, job was done");

             // do a bunch more stuff here
         }
     ];
}
```

I assume that in reality you're doing something that ends up being asynchronous in `DoJob` (or else you'd just wait until the method returns); in that case you might want to use GCD's `dispatch_async` with the result of `dispatch_get_main_queue` to ensure the completion handler takes place back on the main thread.

Joachim Bengtsson has written [a good introductory guide to blocks](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/). As to how they interact with Grand Central Dispatch (and how to use GCD in general), [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html) is good.

Comment: Now you're making it incredibly obvious that I just googled my name :P But if you have an object representing a job, maybe NSOperationQueue will fit better than GCD.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use NSNotificationCenter or write callback method

Comment: Notifications, delegation pattern or callback block, take your pick.

Comment: I've already do this with NSNotificationCenter but I think that callback is better here, and I can't understand how to do callback (